# Nodejs-Request promise get JSON response body from POST

Tags: node.js, request-promise

I'm trying to make a POST request using `request-promise` to an HTTP service which returns back JSON data. I'm using `resolveWithFullResponse` set to true and have the `json` option set to true. I'm also using the `gzip` option if that makes a difference.

Is there anyway I can have `request-promise` automatically convert the response data to JSON? Currently, the response body is a string. Here is what my request options look like:

```
{
   url: 'http://foo.com/getData',
   json: true,
   body: {
      hello: world
   },
   resolveWithFullResponse: true,
   gzip: true
}
```

Comment: If you API return a string in body.data, then it is not possible to convert in json response, you can collect the response and change into JSON using JSON.parse().

Comment: I was looking at something similar to what happens in a GET request
https://github.com/request/request-promise#get-something-from-a-json-rest-api
where the `json:true` option automatically parses the JSON

Answer (score 2):

You should use **transform** option of the request module. Find below the request object.

```
{
   url: 'http://foo.com/getData',
   json: true,
   body: {
      hello: world
   },
   resolveWithFullResponse: true,
   gzip: true,
   transform: function (body, response) {
                if (response.headers['content-type'] === 'application/json') {
                    response.body = JSON.parse(body);
                }
                return response;
            }
}
```